# AWS RDS MySQL Replication with user with REQUIRE SSL

Tags: mysql-replication

I'm trying to set up a MySQL read replica on AWS RDS.

The user for the slave (rdsrepladmin) has the `REQUIRE SSL` flag set.

This causes the read replica server to enter a perpetual 'read replication: connecting' state.

So, I'm read that I need to (on the slave) issue the commands:

```
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1,
START SLAVE;
```

But, the `CHANGE MASTER TO ...` command fails, because I do not have the `super` privilege.
There is no way around this (that I know of), because with a MySQL instance at AWS RDS, only AWS's internal server management accounts have the `super` privilege.

Yet, I fail to believe (yet) that AWS RDS does not support `REQUIRE SSL` for replication connections.

**So, my question is**

How to get the read replica to connect, using SSL/TLS on MySQL instance at AWS RDS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We contacted AWS Support about this issue. They made clear that AWS RDS does not (yet) support SSL for read replicas:

> Unfortunately, **RDS as of now does not support ssl_encryption for setting up external replication**. There is a feature request in place for this, but we don't have an ETA for when this will be implemented: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_external_master.html
>
> Unfortunately, As of now the only option is to have VPN between your source and RDS to have an encrypted tunnel between the instances.

Comment: for those encountering this page as a result of a google search in 2021... the mysql_rds_set_external_master procedure now supports a parameter for SSL that when set seems to be documented as being equivalent to "MASTER_SSL=1, MASTER_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT=0"

Comment: and now having tried this in real life, it does work. :)